# Get row of 2d multi dimensional array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

```
int loadRainData(FILE *fp, char sites[6], double rf[64][6]) {
                    

int row = sizeof(rf) / sizeof(rf[0]);


printf("Number of rows: %d\n", row);


return row;
}
```

I dont understand how to get the amount of rows in my function. There is 7(right now but this is dynamic) values in rf[this guy][6]; I am trying to find how many values there are. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134074/c-size-of-two-dimensional-array has not helped me btw

Comment: Passing in arrays can be problematic because of [array to pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). Don't use `sizeof` to guess how many rows there are, pass that in as an explicit argument. This must be done at the caller, this function does not have the information it needs.

Comment: Hmmm not sure of any other way to do it :(

Comment: I'm kind of baffled you don't know the size here when your signature *literally* says 64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array "decays" into a pointer to the first element when passed to a function.

Check the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html):

> For a two-dimensional array like

```
int array[NROWS][NCOLUMNS];
```

> a reference to array has type ``pointer to array of NCOLUMNS ints,''

in consequence

```
int loadRainData(FILE *fp, char sites[6], double rf[64][6])
```

and

```
int loadRainData(FILE *fp, char sites[6], double (*rf)[6])
```

are the same.

You need to pass the number of rows to the function, so the prototype should be something like:

```
int loadRainData(FILE *fp, char sites[6], size_t rows, double (*rf)[6]);
```

Notice the use of `size_t` instead of `int` (take a look to [What is the correct type for array indexes in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/what-is-the-correct-type-for-array-indexes-in-c))

Comment: Thanks dude. I figured it out but thank you anyway +1